# Как в JS сделать сабмит по форме?

Tags: javascript, submit

Сейчас у меня есть эвент клика по кнопке, а как правильно оформить этот фрагмент кода, чтобы эвент происходил через сабмит по форме?

```js
const inputPlace = document.querySelector('.popup__input_type_place');
const inputLink = document.querySelector('.popup__input_type_link');

createCardButton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const nameAndLink = {
      name: inputPlace.value,
      link: inputLink.value
    };
    cardContent(nameAndLink);
   
    closeAllPopUps(popupAdd); 
    inputPlace.value = inputPlace.textContent; 
    inputLink.value = inputLink.textContent;
  });
```

```css
.popup__container{
    max-width: 430px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    }

@media screen and (max-width: 470px){
.popup__container{
max-width: 270px;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 350px){
    .popup__container{
    max-width: 250px;
    }
    }
```

```html
 <div class="popup popup_function_add">
                <form class="popup__form">
                    <div class ="popup__container">
                        <button type="button" class="popup__close popup_close_add"></button>
                        <h2 class="popup__edit">Новое место</h2>
                        <div class="popup__inputs">
                            <input type="text" name="place" required  class="popup__input popup__input_type_place" placeholder="Место">
                            <input type="text" name="link" required class="popup__input popup__input_type_link" placeholder="Ссылка"></div>
                        <button type="submit" class="popup__save popup__save_create_card">Создать</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть два варианта:

1. Добавить кнопку, сделать её невидимой и вместо отправки выполнить метод `button.click()`.
2. Выполнить метод `form.submit()`.

Comment: Спасибо большое за такой оперативный ответ, я зеленый новичок в JS и все это время пытаюсь освоить эти вещи. 
То есть мы выполняем метод form.submit() Внутри обработчика событий? А что там будет заместо "click" по кнопке тогда? Очень извиняюсь за такие тупые вопросы.

Comment: @Cabagemage если в случае клика по кнопке все поля формы перед этим будут валидироваться, в случае отправки формы через `form.submit()` поля не будут проходит валидацию и вам придётся добавить её в код самостоятельно.

Comment: гигантское спасибо за наводку. Попробую разобраться!